# Multiple branch push issue - prepush Git Hooks using Husky

Tags: git, hook, husky

My problem is quiet simple:

- I'm using Husky to deal with git hooks
- I have configured a prepush hooks that run 2 scripts:

  **"prepush": "npm-run-all --parallel lint test"**
- It's working correctly on single push
- But when I try to push to 2 branches or more, it's not detecting failing scripts.

**For an example, let say that I created 2 branches:**

1. feature/branch-1
2. feature/branch-2

- branch-1 contains a lint issue, branch-2 is clean (no test failing / no lint issue)
- I checkout to branch-2 and push both branches (using SourceTree in my case).

The husky prePush script is called but the lint script does not fail (Haven if it fail when I'm pushing only that branch).

I'm using Husky 0.14.3

Comment: What is not detecting? Can you share a [mcve]?

Comment: @evolutionxbox you are right, I updated the question.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with Husky or the linter. It should return a non-zero value if it fails. What linter are you using?

Comment: I'm using eslint 4.8.0. Iwas thinking to issue with lint but it's working with single push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run tests on a branch that you are not currently on.
If you are on `feature/branch-2` and push `feature/branch-1`, the githook will fire normally and run. But the current state of you application on the filesystem is `feature/branch-2`, so the tests will pass.
You will need to checkout the branch you want to push, before you push.

An alternative would be to run the tests on `pre-commit` instead, that way you will always be on the correct branch.
Or do some scripting that will checkout the correct branch, run the tests, push and put you back on the branch you was before. While possible, probably a bit over-engineered.

Comment: You are completely right, I'm wondering why I didn't think to that in the first case...
Thank you for your answer !